# MySql - How to get a sum of a particular column by joining three tables along with filters

Tags: mysql

There are three tables

1. Inventory - Which contains the stock information
2. Order - Which contains the store information of an order
3. OrderParts - Which contains the Parts associated with the order

**Inventory Table**

[image]

**Order Table**

[image]

**Order Parts Table**

[image]

**Below Expected Report needs to be generated**

[image]

**Query Tried to achieve the above result**

```
SELECT 
    inventory.partNumber, inventory.storeId, SUM(parts.quantity) as orderedQuantity, 
    inventory.availableQuantity
    FROM
        (SELECT *, SUM(availableQuantity) AS availQty
FROM
    inventory AS inventory
GROUP BY storeId , partNumber) AS inventory
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    order
GROUP BY storeId) AS order ON order.storeId = inventory.storeId
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    orderParts) AS parts ON inventory.partNumber = parts.partNumbe    
where inventory.partNumber in ("A1234", "B1234");
GROUP BY order.storeId , parts.partNumber
```

Getting null for Ordered Quantity

[image]

Kindly let me know the way to get the cumulative Ordered quantity as expected. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple method is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select storeid, partnumber,
       sum(availableqty) as availableqty,
       sum(orderedqty) as orderedqty
from (select storeid, partnumber, availableqty, 0 as orderedqty
      from inventory
      union all
      select o.storeid, op.partnumber, 0, op.quantity
      from orderparts op join
           orders o
           on op.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
     ) sp
group by storeid, partnumber;
```

Your question doesn't explicitly describe the filters, but you can add filters in either the subqueries or the outer query.